# Cloud Firestore Pricing per read

Tags: javascript, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am having the following block of code .Which is using Angular fire 2 to get data from Cloud Firestore . The code is working fine . But after normal usage and testing i soon crossed my daily quota of free limit of 50,000 reads .

I would like to know if the result set returns list of 200 items. Does Firestore counts that to be no of reads as 1 or 200 .(As per the code you can see that is only one query)?

More over as per their quota and limits document if one of the data in the list is changed/modified that is considered to be one more read . Is this for all returned records or for each records? Is this applicable even when we use `take(1)`?

```
menuCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Menu>;
menues: any;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private router : Router) { }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.menuCol = this.afs.collection('MenuItems');


        this.menues = this.menuCol.snapshotChanges().take(1)
          .map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;

              return { id, data };
            });
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) says this for the quota for Cloud Firestore for a project on the free/Spark plan:

> **Document reads**: 50K/day

As the name says, this counts the number of documents that Firestore reads on your behalf. So a single query that reads 200 documents, will count as 200.

Your current code will request all documents, return one, and then detach the observer. So that will read all of them.

If you want to read only one document, pass in the limit to the observable:

```
 collection('MenuItems', ref => ref.limit(1))
```